# Checking open UDP Port in C++

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, port, port-scanning

How can I check if a remote UDP port is open by using native C++? Since UDP is connection-less, calling `connect()` is not helpful. I cannot try binding it since it is not local. `nmap` cannot also indicate. (however `netstat` can find out, but I think it looks at internal information about open ports/files). Is there anyway to detect it? If I go a layer down on network level, is it possible to send a ICMP message by C++ to check port-unreachable status? I mean, would that give enough information on port status?

Platform is Linux.

Comment: "Native C++" on what OS/platform?

Comment: The language is not the issue here as much as the privilege level at which your code is executing. For example you could, just like `nmap`, make use of the `libpcap` library from your C++ code. Also, I think if you try all the options of `nmap` you'll get at least an indication about whether the port is likely open or filtered, even if not with 100% certainty in all cases. What options with `netstat` and `nmap` where you using?

Comment: netstat -lptun indicates there is a UDP port open at port 1060, however it seems I forgot -sU for nmap. It requires root access to find out (and it finds out correctly), why?

Comment: (concerning `nmap`) it's low-level enough. It basically makes use of certain heuristics in order to classify whether the observed behavior means a port is open or not. But because this is so low-level it requires super-user rights.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED None of this has anything to do with a remote port.

Comment: @EJP: oh? Please explain to me why certain socket operations are only allowed for privileged users then? `traceroute` for example is limited on some systems for that very reason. I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED That question is also irrelevant. He is talking about the status of a remote port. Privileges on the local system have nothing to do with it. He needs to communicate with the remote system, and he doesn't need privileges to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to determine whether or not a UDP port on a remote machine is being passed through a firewall and/or has an application running on it.

You cannot reliably determine this.  The closest you can come is to try sending a series of small datagrams to that address and port, spaced about 1 second apart for about 10 seconds.

If there are no firewalls blocking the port and no application is running, then the remote system might send back `ICMP_UNREACH_PORT` (port unreachable).  If there are no blocking firewalls and the remote system is down, a router might send back `ICMP_UNREACH_HOST` or `ICMP_UNREACH_NET`.  If a firewall is blocking you, it might send back `ICMP_UNREACH_FILTER_PROHIB`, but most firewalls don't send back anything.

The odds of getting any of those back are pretty slim because most firewalls block that sort of ICMP feedback.  Even if an ICMP message does come back, linux generally does not let you see it unless you are running as root.  Some operating systems will report ICMP errors as a failure of the next `sendto()` to the same address/port, which is why you need to repeat the message several times.  But some do not, in which case you must open a specific ICMP port and parse any return messages.

Even if you do somehow get an ICMP message, understand that they are not reliable.  For example, you could get `ICMP_UNREACH_PORT` even though an application is not only listening, but actively sending you data.  (That's rare, but I've seen it happen.)

If an application is running on the given port and if you know what that application is and if you know how to craft a message which will cause that application to respond to you, then doing so and getting a response is the best indication that the port is open.  But getting no response means nothing: maybe the port is blocked, maybe the application is not running, or maybe it just didn't like your message.

Bottom line: no, not really.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bulletproof way to check if a remote port is ready to receive your UDP datagrams. Since UDP is connectionless you can just tell if the remote host is answering something meaningful to you. There may be ways to get an hint (as port scanners do) but that is nothing I would rely on in production code.