# How do I check if a remote UDP port is open?

Tags: rust, udp

In order to check if I can reach a particular TCP port, I use:

```
TcpStream::connect_timeout(&socket, Duration...
```

There is no clear equivalent with UdpSocket, so would like to know what would work similarly. The closest I could find is using the `set_write_timeout`, then doing a `send` or `send_to`, but these yield wrong results in that they show that the connection is successful, when the port is not even open on the other side.

Comment: If it matters, I want to check if openvpn is running on remote, port 1194

Comment: This is not really specific to Rust. There is no good and reliable way to check whether a UDP port is open because UDP is a send-and-forget protocol. You also won't get confirmation that messages have actually been received, that's why all `send` seem to be successful.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539898/how-to-check-if-remote-udp-port-is-open-c

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886228/checking-open-udp-port-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking open UDP Port in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886228/checking-open-udp-port-in-c)

Answer (score -5):

Contrary to other answers and comments, there is a way. Connect to it with `connect()` and try a few sends. If the API is written correctly you should eventually get an error corresponding to the underlying ICMP UNREACHABLE message that is sent if the remote port isn't there.

Comment: *If the API is written correctly* — Which API? Can you prove this one way or the other for the OPs question?

Comment: @Shepmaster There is no necessity to prove documented behaviour.

Comment: @dowvoters No error here. Your point?